# zerobrane autocomplete when loading external module via "require"

Tags: lua, zerobrane

I got a question about autocomplete functionality:

let's say in my project I have two files:

globals.lua:

```
local M={}
M.platform=nil
M.superhub=true
M.gamehub=false
return M
```

and main.lua:

```
......some code....
local glb=require("globals")
```

my question is about - how do I get autocomplete to show

- platform
- superhub
- gamehub

upon typing `glb.` when editing main.lua file

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported in the current version of ZeroBrane Studio (1.70), but there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/609) with some discussion on this topic.

Comment: Thank you Paul, amazing piece of software, will definitely donate when my game is finished.